# Building an API with/without OAuth and OpenID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth, openid

I need to develop an API to be the core of a web APP.
My initial idea was making a REST API that would treat all the request and then create some clients for web, mobile and desktop.

My question is, How should I manage the authentication for this situation?
I thought about using a token that would be passed with all requests to the REST API.
Im my case, I would not like to have something like OAuth because the ecosystem will not have multiple apps like Facebook/Twitter does.
NOTE: I must have the API separated from the client for web.

In more details, I would request POST /users/auth passing their password and username, and receive an auth token.

Is it a good approach or there is something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a fantastic gem that handles authentication in rails apps. It also provides token based authentication. You can find many resources on the web (for example [here](http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/)) explainig how to use it. No doubt it will fit for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Agree that Devise is great for the auth in the application. For the API level, 3scale could help a lot (http://www.3scale.net) - it takes care of rate limits, keys, oauth secret distribution, analytics, developer portal and other stuff. There's a ruby plugin to get started here: https://github.com/3scale/3scale_ws_api_for_ruby.

Comment: It looks very interesting. I'm gonna check it out.